# Android Action bar buttons wont show up with navigation drawer with fragmentactivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

i am trying to show some buttons in actionbar but they just dont show up
i have successfully implemented the navigation drawer and viewpager using fragments
the implementes for showing menu inflator and action bar buttons has also been done but they just wont show up

in menu/main.xml i have added app:showAsAction="always" but still it wont show up

here is the

detailactivity.java

```
package com.test.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import com.Blog.gkgyan.parser.RSSFeed;


//public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    RSSFeed feed;
    int pos;
    private DescAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private  String[] planets;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.detail);

        //Drawer Layout
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Drawer closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Drawer opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);;

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//      try {
//          ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
//          Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
//          if (menuKeyField != null) {
//              menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
//              menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
//          }
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {        
            try { 
                ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
                Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey"); 

                if(menuKeyField != null) { 
                    menuKeyField.setAccessible(true); 
                    menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        }


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
        planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets ));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // Get the feed object and the position from the Intent
        feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");
        pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");

        // Initialize the views
        adapter = new DescAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Set Adapter to pager:
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(pos);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //@Override
    //public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        Intent i = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rate:
            String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";

            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));
            startActivity(i);
            //return true;
            break;

        case R.id.action_share:
            i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello from Hansel and Petal!");
            i.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(i);
            //return true;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListener.syncState();
    }

    public class DescAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public DescAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return feed.getItemCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            DetailFragment frag = new DetailFragment();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);
            bundle.putInt("pos", position);
            frag.setArguments(bundle);

            return frag;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GkcategoryListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (position == 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GkcategoryListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    }

}
```

`

and menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.Blog.gkgyan.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_rate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_important"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_rate"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

i wan to show the action_share and Action_rate butons in action bar on **detailactivity.java** tried every thing nothing  works on this page

however it does work perfectly fine in  main activity.java

here is the code

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent intent = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rate:
            String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.action_share:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello from Hansel and Petal!");
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void latestActivity(View v){
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GkcategoryListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    }


}
```

is it a issue with fragment activity or navigation drawer any help would be great please mention where is should make changes in my code